# Sending multiple requests from users search

Tags: bug, search

I tried to search for a user in [Users Tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) and accidentally my enter key accidentally got stuck because it's sticky, and this happened.

The search spammed the website with lots of requests and the result was this:

[image]

And the website said...

[image]

This also happened in the Stack Overflow users tab and then I saw some popups with the messages saying my IP address sent multiple request.

Please don't block me this was just an accident.

Comment: *"It's not you, it's us. **This is our fault.**"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to try it for the sake of it, and recreated as displayed in your post. After trying to navigate back to this question I got the following message displayed in my browser:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Access was restored pretty quickly though.

Some form of client side throttling would prevent such issues for ***all users*** with a sticky <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or users with cats that like to sleep on the keyboard.

[image]